# Code refactoring - initialize class from array

Tags: ruby

I am just wondering if there is any best way to initialize the class instance from array:

```
def initialize(row)
    @name        = row[2]
    @description = row[3]
    @status      = row[5]
    ....
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am usually using the following style:

```
def initialize row
  @name, @description, @status = *row
end
```

If you need to ignore some arguments you can do the following:

```
ignored, ignored, @name, @description, ignored, @status = *row
```

Or shorter:

```
_, _, @name, @description, _, @status = *row
```

Comment: +1, I usually use the underscore version. But then one should also wonder if `row` should be a hash with descriptive key names...

Answer (score 6):

If you have to work with data like

```
row = [ 0, 1, 'Smith', 'red nose', 3, 'awake']
```

and you have to go by the position of the fields, then your code is OK. You could shorten it like this:

```
def initialize (row)
  @name, @description, @status = row.values_at(2,3,5) # things like (5,2,3) are allowed.
end
```

Answer (score 2):

in my opinion you should not use such style of initialization because it is very error-prone

class interface must be explicit and visible from first glance so instead of

```
def method(array_of_attributes)
```

stick to

```
def method(meaningful_name_1, meaningful_name_2, options={})
```

as it is then much easier to see what method expects from both auto-generated docs and from looking at method definition

also there is nothing wrong with passing array of attributes to a method if that is essential for you:

```
def method_one
  arguments_for_method_two = [name, description, status]
  method_two(*arguments_for_method_two)
end

def method_two(name, description, status)
  # blah ...
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind doing some meta-programming (just keeps all names and indices together in one place):

```
{:name => 2, :description => 3, :status => 5}.each do |name, i| 
  instance_variable_set("@#{name}", row[i]) 
end
```